# Why does the output csv file not display the expected result?

Tags: python, csv

```
import glob
from datetime import date
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import islice
path = 'C:/Users/Calum/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Python Programs/Brunel Forecasts/November/*.csv'
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    with open (fname) as f:
        readCSV = csv.reader ((islice(f, 24, None)), delimiter = ';')
        irrad_fore = []
        timestamp = []
        day = []
        month = []
        year = []
        for row in readCSV:
            irrad1 = row[4]
            time = row[3]
            d = row[2]
            m = row[1]
            y = row[0]

            irrad_fore.append(irrad1)
            timestamp.append(time)
            day.append(d)
            month.append(m)
            year.append(y)

            out = csv.writer(open('C:/Users/Calum/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Python Programs/Brunel Forecasts/forecast_11-2016.csv','w', newline=''), delimiter=';')
            for values in zip(year, month, day, timestamp, irrad_fore):
                 x = values
                 out.writerow(x)
```

Why does the output csv file only contain the final days worth of data where as when I just print the variable x to the screen it contains the data for the whole month?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

it seems to me that what you are trying to achieve (basically concatenate all files?) is something like this:

```
path = 'C:/Users/Calum/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Python Programs/Brunel Forecasts/November/*.csv'

irrad_fore = []
timestamp = []
day = []
month = []
year = []

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    with open (fname) as f:
        readCSV = csv.reader ((islice(f, 24, None)), delimiter = ';')

        for row in readCSV:
            irrad1 = row[4]
            time = row[3]
            d = row[2]
            m = row[1]
            y = row[0]

            irrad_fore.append(irrad1)
            timestamp.append(time)
            day.append(d)
            month.append(m)
            year.append(y)

out = csv.writer(open('C:/Users/Calum/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Python Programs/Brunel Forecasts/forecast_11-2016.csv','w', newline=''), delimiter=';')
for values in zip(year, month, day, timestamp, irrad_fore):
    x = values
    out.writerow(x)
```

although it would be probably better to write the csv file directly without aggregating everything into the temporary lists:

```
path = 'C:/Users/Calum/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Python Programs/Brunel Forecasts/November/*.csv'
out = csv.writer(open('C:/Users/Calum/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Python Programs/Brunel Forecasts/forecast_11-2016.csv','w', newline=''), delimiter=';')

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    with open (fname) as f:
        readCSV = csv.reader ((islice(f, 24, None)), delimiter = ';')

        for row in readCSV:
            irrad1 = row[4]
            time = row[3]
            d = row[2]
            m = row[1]
            y = row[0]

            out.writerow([y,m,d,time,irrad1])
```

Comment: Thanks that does solve the problem however when I move the statement to the beginning or before the for statement it causes the order of the output to be completely muddled which I don't understand why?

Comment: @C.Deakin I am not sure whether I understood your question - are you are trying to basically concatenate the csv files? I have update the answer to reflect this...